# mysql huge operations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am currently importing a huge CSV file from my iPhone to a rails server. In this case, the server will parse the data and then start inserting rows of data into the database. The CSV file is fairly large and would take a lot time for the operation to end.

Since I am doing this asynchronously, my iPhone is then able to go to other views and do other stuff.

However, when it requests another query in another table.. this will HANG because the first operation is still trying to insert the CSV's information into the database.

Is there a way to resolve this type of issue?

Comment: What engine are you using? You need an engine like InnoDB, which has record-level locking rather than table-level locking.

Comment: I am using mysql database... not sure what you mean by engine.

Comment: That's not an engine, that's a database. MySQL has a number of different engines that can be selected for each table: InnoDB, MyISAM, etc. They store the data differently and have different locking mechanisms and performance characteristics.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement: _the CSV will parse the data and then start inserting rows of data into the database_ By CSV, you mean comma-separated-values file? How can a CSV file parse anything?

Comment: why would locking be an issue though when I am only inserting a huge loads of data... and i'm querying another table.. i might query in the same table in the future though

Comment: I didn't know you were querying a different table, the question was not that detailed.

Comment: I have edited my original posts to make things clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [content types of insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443274/content-types-of-insertion)

Comment: @RowlandShaw: They are clearly two different questions. If you actually read them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the phone doesn't care when the database insert is complete, you might want to try storing the CSV file in a tmp directory on your server and then have a script write from that file to the database. Or simply store it in memory. That way, once the phone has posted the CSV file, it can move on to other things while the script handles the database inserts asynchronously. And yes, @Barmar is right about using an InnoDB engine rather than MyISAM (which may be default in some configurations).

Or, you might want to consider enabling "low-priority updates" which will delay write calls until all pending read calls have finished. See [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html) about MySQL table locking. (I'm not sure what exactly you say is hanging: the update, or reads while performing the update…)

Regardless, if you are posting the data asynchronously from your phone (i.e., not from the UI thread), it shouldn't be an issue as long as you don't try to use more than the maximum number of concurrent HTTP connections.

Comment: The phone should not care about database inserts since it is running an asynchronous HTTP request to the server.

I am interested in using a script to handle the database inserts asynchronously. Upload the CSV file to the database and having a script to interpret if a new file is received in the folder.

Would a single user be allowed to connect to multiple instances of the database allowing multiple connections to the database or must I be using a different username to connect to the database to allow multiple connections to the database?

Comment: What I mean by hanging is the first transaction is ongoing while the next requested queries are waiting for the first transaction to finish then it will process.

Comment: A user can have multiple connections. You can even regulate how many simultaneous connections are allowed. Check out [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html) in the MySQL docs.

Comment: And as for the hang, if you enable low-priority updates, the update queue will wait for any queued reads to finish before continuing.